# Get the row at 60% of the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to select the row at 60% of a table with Oracle. I can find the number of the 60% row with:

```
select round(count(*)*0.60) as sira from 
    (select to_date(time) as tarih,lenght as hiz  from table order by length desc)
```

I'm looking for the **name** column data for the row at 60%.  That is, 60% of all rows should have a higher length than the selected row.

For example, for this data:

```
name   time    length
r1     10:00   1
r2     10:02   2
r3     10:04   3
...
r10    10:20   10
```

I'm looking for a query that prints `r4` (row at 60% ordered by decreasing **length**.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by yt.length desc) as rn
        ,       count(*) over () as cnt
        ,       yt.*
        from    YourTable yt
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = round(cnt * 0.60)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8771e/1/0)

Comment: This will never return any rows, because you cannot use rownum = n with n > 1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855422/oracle-sql-why-does-query-select-from-records-where-rownum-5-and-rownum

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: Interesting, perhaps it can be done with `row_number()`

Comment: Either that, or you return the rownum value from the inner query and use that value to filter in the outer one, sth like select * from (select rownum as rn, ... from ... ) where rn = (select round(cnt * 0.60) from yourtable. But I prefer the approach with windowing functions.

Comment: My first answer didn't work in SQL Fiddle, would be surprised if it worked for you!

Comment: You can adjust the `(order by ...)` after `row_number()` to adjust the ordering

Comment: @Andamor excuse me, I tested your first answer is not working